Does different ばかり placement in a sentence affect the meaning?
This is taken from Dictionary of Japanese Grammar (Intermediate) in the section about くせに

彼は大学生のくせに漫画ばかり読んでいる。
Although he is a college student, all he does is read comics.

But I want to focus on ばかり. Is the translation of this sentence correct? Or is it "Although he is a college student, the only thing he reads is comics."? (Doesn't imply that he doesn't do other activities)
And if I want to say that "...He does nothing but reads comics" the sentence would be like this?

彼は大学生のくせに漫画を読んでばかりいる。

